# Why is my `'Text()`scaled up on some phones while rotating

Tags: flutter, transform

While waiting for an upcoming event, I slowly roll a `Text()` showing an emoji.

I use the code below:

```dart
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(contentPadding),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: color,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40))),
            child: widget.status == null
                ? Column(children: [
                    Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Transform(
                              transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(rot.value),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Text(
                                text,
                                style: style,
                              )),
                          CircularProgressIndicatorWithOptions(),
                        ]),
                    Text(sumUp),
                  ])
                : Column(children: [
                    Text(text, style: style),
                    Text(""),
                    Text(sumUp),
                  ])));
```

Here is the issue that appears only on some android phones:

[image]

And on others phones, it is ok:

[image]

How to make sure the text keeps is intrinsic natural size? (aka, not using a SizedBox with a specific size).

Comment: did you try setting a `fontSize` that is relative to the `Size` of the screen that your app is displayed on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a workaround by adding a small scale as follows:

```dart
Transform.scale(
  scale: 0.96,
  child: Transform.rotate(
    angle: _turnsAnim.value,
    child: Text(text, style: style))),
```

I believe that on some phones, the widget comes out of bounding box which triggers the scale up effect.

I put more time soon to try to demonstrate this hypothesis.